# How to build task 'minitest'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm trying to run minitest.
I followed a few videos on how to get it running, but none of them seem to get me around this message

Don't know how to build task 'minitest'

I think I must be missing a step or gem or something that the videos don't account for. 
But I don't have a clue what step that is..

Here's my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'pg'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
  gem 'guard-bundler'
  gem 'guard-rails'
  gem 'html2haml'
  gem 'hub', :require=>nil
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'rb-fchange', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-fsevent', :require=>false
  gem 'rb-inotify', :require=>false
end
group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'minitest-spec-rails'
  gem 'minitest-wscolor'
  gem 'minitest-rails'
end
```

My Rake file looks like this.

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

ComCon::Application.load_tasks
```

Test helper

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"
require "minitest/rails"

# To add Capybara feature tests add `gem "minitest-rails-capybara"`
# to the test group in the Gemfile and uncomment the following:
# require "minitest/rails/capybara"

# Uncomment for awesome colorful output
# require "minitest/pride"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.(yml|csv) for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

And finally  my test file

```
require 'test_helper'

class RepositoryTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @repo = Repository.new
  end

  def test_valid
    @repo.is_valie?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `minitest-rails` out of the `test` group in your Gemfile. The rake tasks are defined in that gem and are not available because you aren't in the test environment when you run `rake`.